# How to output environment variable to Grails log4j log file

Tags: grails, log4j

I have the following file appender and I'm wanting the specific environment to be output to the log file whenever a message is logged:

```
appenders {
        rollingFile name:'mtagradepush_file', 
                    maxFileSize: 2048, 
                    file: "${globalDirs.logDirectory}${appName}.log".toString(), 
                    layout:pattern(conversionPattern: "[Env:${app.log.env}] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n")
}
```

This conversion pattern worked when I used it in a log4j.properties file in a normal Java app, but now when using it with Grails it's not printing the value of the environment to the log file.

The app.log.env variable is being set in CATALINA_OPTS when the Tomcat 6 server starts up, like this:

> export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx2000m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
>   -Dapp.log.env=DEVL..."

If it's not possible to reference this variable then is there a way to grab the Grails environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat the `${}` as a block of Groovy code and do a `${System.getProperty('app.log.env')}`